# C#.Net : How to make my listview items clickable 

Tags: c#, .net, regex, listview, listviewitem

I am creating a tool in Visual C#.Net. The algorithm of the tool is to check for all space/s before/after a parenthesis and create an error message for the found errors. 
For example: input is ( Text )
Error will be raise because space before and after the parenthesis is detected.
If errors are found the code will add the errors in listview1.items().

To make my question much clearer for you here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int error_counter = 0;
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            //requirement 8c
            //check for a space in open and close parenthesis
            Regex test = new Regex(@"\(\s.+\s\)|\[\s.+\s\]|\{\s.+\s\}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matchlist = test.Matches(richTextbox1.Text);
            if (matchlist.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < matchlist.Count; i++)
                {
                    Match firstMatch = matchlist[i];
                    string firstMatch_string = firstMatch.ToString();
                    string[] errors = new string[matchlist.Count];
                    errors[i] = "Ommit Space between a bracket";
                    listView1.Items.Add(errors[i]);
                    error_counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

What I looking for is that all of the items of my listview1 will be clickable, and after a click was made by the user the tool will highlight the error found in the richtextbox1.

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: You might want to look into client side scripting with jQuery to achieve this.

Comment: You mean I can't create that kind of thing with C# only?

Comment: Not about your question, you should use the static method Regex.Matches most of the time (except if you know what is the difference with the instance method and are making an optimisation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already told you, use the Index and Length properties of the Match class. Here's a short example implementing a weird textbox selection strategy. But it works effectively demonstrating the concept:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errors = new List<Error>();
        listView1.Items.Clear();                                    
        foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"(\(\s+|\s+\)|\[\s+|\s+\]|\{\s+|\s+\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {                           
            //you may decide to differentiate the msg according to the specific problem
            Error error = new Error(m, "Ommit Space between a bracket");
            this.errors.Add(error);
            listView1.Items.Add(error.msg);                
        }            
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            Error error = errors[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]];
            Select(richTextBox1, error);
        }
    }

    private static void Select(RichTextBox rtb, Error e) {
        string o = rtb.Text;
        rtb.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < o.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i >= e.index && i <= e.index + e.length)
            {
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.White;
                rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            }
            rtb.AppendText(o[i].ToString());
        }
    }              
}

public class Error
{

    public int index;
    public int length;
    public string value;
    public string msg;

    public Error(Match m, string msg)
    {
        this.index = m.Index;
        this.length = m.Length;
        this.value = m.Value;
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: this probably is the answer that I am looking for. I will try this one and will update you guys if I've found the right answer thanks!

Comment: I already fix the issue on my project! Super thanks a lot! Really big help!! Diego thanks again!

Comment: The only problem here is that if the string input in the richTextbox1 has many lines, I mean if the input is too many it slows down when you click an error in the listview, because it searches so many characters. How can I minimize that kind of thing? thanks

Comment: in that case the problem is not the regular expression but what I already called a weird text selection strategy. As you can see on the code I embedded its logic on the Select method. I'm not skilled on winform gui tricks and I have no idea how to get better performance when selecting text. My (weird) strategy involved to clear the textbox and write everything again choosing a specific text color for slices of text if they hit the error (index+length) text space. You may even need a better thirdy part textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

The Match object (like firstMatch) has two usefull properties here : [Index and Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx).

They give you the position and the length of the match in question in the original text.
With that in your knowledge, you just have to implement the highlight in the richTextBox !

Comment: And if you have trouble with making listviewitem clickable and detecting wich item was clicked, first specify what technology you are using : WinForms ? WPF ?

Comment: I am using WinForms. Thanks for the answer!